# Programming multi-threaded batch in X++. Not working for some reason?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

Code is pretty straight forward.  From the Vendor Details form, if you go Functions>Update 1099, a user wants to do this wide open on all of the vendors instead of manually doing it.  I modified the base VendTax1099Update class to extend RunBaseBatch, then added a bunch of parm methods.  I'm getting this error, but the task exists?  Am I doing it wrong?

"The dependency could not be created because task Vendor update of tax 1099 information does not exist."

I made it "addDependency" because there were DB locks when I tried to run it wide open.  Not sure if there is a way to fix those.

```
void run()
{
    BatchHeader         batchHeader;
    VendTax1099Update   vendTax1099Update;
    VendTax1099Update   vendTax1099UpdateOld;
    VendTable           vendTable;
    boolean             first = true;
    ;

    /*
    if (this.isInBatch())
    {
    */
        // Make sure there is a batch header
        if (!batchHeader)
            batchHeader = BatchHeader::construct(this.parmCurrentBatch().BatchJobId);

        while select vendTable
            where vendTable.Tax1099Reports      == true     &&
                  vendTable.Tax1099Box          != ''
        {
            if (Tax1099Fields::exist(vendTable.Tax1099Box))
            {
                vendTax1099Update = new VendTax1099Update();
                vendTax1099Update.parmFromDate(fromDate);
                vendTax1099Update.parmToDate(toDate);
                vendTax1099Update.parmRecalcAmounts(recalcAmounts);
                vendTax1099Update.parmSetAll1099(setAll1099);
                vendTax1099Update.parmBoxFor1099(vendTable.Tax1099Box);
                vendTax1099Update.parmVendorNum(vendTable.AccountNum);

                if (first)
                {
                    batchHeader.addRuntimeTask(vendTax1099Update, this.parmCurrentBatch().RecId);
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (vendTax1099UpdateOld)
                        batchHeader.addDependency(vendTax1099Update, vendTax1099UpdateOld, BatchDependencyStatus::FinishedOrError);
                }

                vendTax1099UpdateOld = vendTax1099Update;
            }
            else
                error (strfmt("Unable to process %1 because %2 was not found in Tax1099Fields", vendTable.AccountNum, vendTable.Tax1099Box));
        }
    /*
    }
    */

    if (batchHeader)
        batchHeader.save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been racking my brain for a couple hours on this and of course minutes after posting I figure the issue out after realizing I can step into the batchHeader.addDependency() method.

Turns out you have to add the task, then set the dependency.  I thought setting the dependency was also adding the task in the same swoop.  The corrected bit of code is this:

```
            vendTax1099Update.parmBoxFor1099(vendTable.Tax1099Box);
            vendTax1099Update.parmVendorNum(vendTable.AccountNum);

            batchHeader.addRuntimeTask(vendTax1099Update, this.parmCurrentBatch().RecId);

            if (vendTax1099UpdateOld)
                batchHeader.addDependency(vendTax1099Update, vendTax1099UpdateOld, BatchDependencyStatus::FinishedOrError);

            vendTax1099UpdateOld = vendTax1099Update;
        }
        else
```